# Magento2 weird checkout page issue on click of Proceed to Checkout button

Tags: magento2, checkout, redirect, checkout-page

Why does my checkout page navigate from **checkout/cart** to **/checkout** instead of **checkout/onepage/success** even though i have not done any modification to the Checkout module in magento 2

This issue popped up all of a sudden, it happens when i click on 'Proceed to Checkout' button

No errors in var/log or system log does not say anything related to this!!

Where might be the issue?

Comment: my URL hits till checkout/#payment and at this point in console browser it says: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

Comment: how to redirect to shopping cart page by clicking proceed to checkout button in magento2 . And which file need to add in our custom module